# Retrieving Inner Text of Html Tag C#

Tags: c#, innertext

I have a string that contains html. Inside of this string there is an html tag and I want to retrieve the inner text of that. How can I do that in C#?

Here is the html tag whose inner text I want to retrieve:

```
<td width="100%" class="container">
```

Comment: You can use the tilde character {`} to mark code blocks.

Comment: The full manual: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: i prefer the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

---

*Edit* something like this (not tested)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
string html = /* whatever */;
doc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach(HtmlNode td in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//td[@class='container']")
{
    string text = td.InnerText;
    // do whatever with text
}
```

You can also select the text directly with [a different XPath selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872901/xpath-select-innertext).

---

Related questions:

- [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)
- [HTMLAgilityPack parse in the InnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346144/htmlagilitypack-parse-in-the-innerhtml)
- [C#: HtmlAgilityPack extract inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text)

Comment: Can you load an html document from a string that contains the html in it? or do I have to give it a path?

Comment: Answered my own question: instead of using Load use LoadHtml intead. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

try with regex.

```
public string GetInnerTextFromHtml(string htmlText)
{
    //Match any Html tag (opening or closing tags) 
    // followed by any successive whitespaces
    //consider the Html text as a single line

    Regex regex = new Regex("(<.*?>\\s*)+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    
    // replace all html tags (and consequtive whitespaces) by spaces
    // trim the first and last space

    string resultText = regex.Replace(htmlText, " ").Trim();

    return resultText;
}
```